# Triple boot grub problem

Tags: grub2

I had a dual boot system, currently Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.3, and this setup has worked fine over multiple laptops and upgrades. I wanted to try out Android-X86, as there some Android only apps that I sometimes use. Bluestacks is too slow, both to load and run, and it would cut down on the stuff I need to carry around.

I finally plucked up the courage to install Android-X86 and all seemed fine. The X86 grub picked up on Windows and Linux, and installed a seemingly functional grub, the only oddity was if I selected Ubuntu, I was dropped into my old pre-x86 grub, where there was another working windows entry.
A few months ago, I switched on my laptop, and all non-X86 entries had vanished. When I restarted the laptop, the Ubuntu and Windows entries reappeared. Today, the same thing happened, but several restart made no difference. I was able to get to Windows by changing the BIOS boot sequence, but couldn't find a way into Linux.
I could access the grub config from windows using Linux Reader, and thought I would be able the edit the Android-X86 grub and put the Windows and Linux entries in there. I could not find a way to do this. 
I am also curious about the reason for the missing entries. It can't be hardware, because changing the BIOS sequence proved that the disk was OK. Windows and Ubuntu were still missing from the X86 grub.

A little while later, the missing grub entries re-appeared in the X86 grub, so the problem has gone away. The upgrade-grub command does not seem to detect android as an OS, so I am stuck with Android on the front end. All OS's are in different partitions on the same disc.

Does anyone know how the Android-X86 grub works? Is it dynamically constructed? Could there be two different version lurking? Is it possible to edit the grub somehow? I would at least like a direct link to Ubuntu rather than 2 grubs and the possibility of replacing missing entries if the same problem returns.

Comment: `grub` is a GNU program (https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) and should operate the same on all systems, with minor exceptions being grub version 1 works different to grub 2 (menu wise). Each installed system can have its own `grub` installed, but your BIOS will control which drive's MBR is booted (assuming BIOS and not UEFI) which controls which `grub` code is run.   `grub` is not the only bootloader available (Ubuntu will also use others, eg. `lilo`) however is Android-X86 uses `grub` it'll be standard grub; just look at version, or were you referring to grub as any boot-loader?